# Rebranding Android 1.6

Tags: android, android-widget

What is some advice to re-branding an Android phone (Android 1.6). My goal is to limit its functionality. For example, only make calls possible to a specified number as well as its messaging feature, change its boot animation, disabling any extra feature.

Can I do that using an "application", and of course, I'm concerned about its security, meaning that, this "application" cannot be removed. Well yes, re-flashing the phone is out of my security concern. This application should start and taking over the system when it is started up.

Comment: while i am obviously ignorant of your reasoning behind this, that sounds terrible! that aside, wouldn't it be easier to just get a crappy feature/flip phone? or one of those once they make for old people and children that can only dial preprogrammed numbers? it sounds like what you want to make is not an application but a rom that could be flashed to your target device.

Comment: well yes, your comment is surely make sense. A rom to be flashed to the device should do it. What i'm intending to do is, creating a device (android 1.6 device), that is limited its functionality, once it's boot up, contact internet server and authenticating, and can only browse internet, yet again, the allowed URLs. 

Is there any API or SDK, or Application that can do this? No ROM flashing if possible.

Comment: im not sure if that is possible without flashing a rom or having a whole suite of applications, what your describing sounds like a complete takeover of operations or lockdown which would mean (to the best of my knowledge) that your app(s) would have to intercept intents for basically everything, which, as far as i know, would be a lot more work. in addition, i dont think that an app can have that kind of authority over a system, at least without superuser, and for that you have to root, and if youre going to root, then you might as well just write and flash a rom.

Comment: well maybe something like this, my app hook into calling event, if the destination number is not allowed, my app instantly cancel the calls. and so does the messaging. is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with an application.  You'd need to build your own customized system image for the device and flash that on to it.  To be able to do that, you need to have the hardware drivers and other support needed to make a full working system image.  You can look at CyanogenMod as one place to see if someone has put together a working system image for it, but for something down to 1.6 it seems unlikely to me.  Most people are trying to get newer versions of the platform to run on their devices, not old ones.

Comment: OK. if so, can i do this; customizing a device, and then extracting its system image, and apply it to another device, the same spec, hardware, brand image?